# Python. Asynchronous function raises exception and try catch doesn't help to catch it

Tags: python, exception, python-asyncio

I'm doing bot for working with Bitmax market. Here's the class of Bot. It's connected to Bitmax by websocket and REST, and it also makes a REST server for web client.

```
class MarketBot:
    async def handle_data(self):
        @self.ws.add_dispatcher(name='receiver')
        async def handler(msg):
            if msg['m'] == 'order':
                try:
                    order_id = msg['data']['orderId']
                    status = msg['data']['st']
                    if status in ('Filled', 'PartiallyFilled'):
                        raw = f'Ордер на бирже Bitmax сработал'
                        if self.sms_on:
                            await self.sms.send_sms([self.sms_phone], raw)
                    elif status != 'New':
                        self._logger.info(status)
                except Exception as exc:
                    self._logger.exception(exc)
                    raise exc

        while True:
            try:
                await self.ws.handle_messages(close_exc=False)
            except self.ws.WSClosed as exc:
                await self.ws.__aenter__()
                continue

        return result
    async def bot(self):
        try:
            await self.subscribe_to_channel(
                f'order:cash', id='abc')

            self.tasks = asyncio.gather(
                self.handle_data(),
                self.handle_rate(),
                self.send_from_queue(),
            )

            await self.tasks
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            return None
```

Here's the class for working with WebSocket connection

```
class BitmaxWebSocket:
    async def dispatch(self, message):
        if message.type in (
            aiohttp.WSMsgType.CLOSE,
            aiohttp.WSMsgType.CLOSED,
            aiohttp.WSMsgType.CLOSING,
        ):
            exc = self.WSClosed(f'Dispatch: WebSocket apparently closed\n{message}')
            self._logger.error(message)
            raise exc
        elif message.type != aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            exc = ValueError(f'Non-text message\n{message}')
            self._logger.exception(exc)
            raise exc
        try:
            data = message.json()
            if data['m'] == 'ping':
                if int(data['hp']) < 3:
                    self._logger.warning(data)
                await self.send_json(op='pong', data={})
            else:
                for dispatcher in self._dispatchers:
                    asyncio.create_task(dispatcher.func(data))
        except ValueError as exc:
            self._logger.exception(exc)
            raise exc

    async def handle_messages(self, close_exc=True):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.is_closed():
                    raise self.WSClosed('Handling: WebSocket apparently closed')
                message = await self._ws_connection.receive()
                message = await self.dispatch(message)
            except self.WSClosed as exc:
                self._logger.exception(exc)
                if close_exc:
                    raise exc
                await self.__aenter__()
                continue
            except Exception as exc:
                self._logger.exception(exc)
                raise exc
```

It raises this error but it doesn't continue to work.

```
[13:56:58 22.10.2020] level=ERROR  Dispatch: WebSocket apparently closed
WSMessage(type=<WSMsgType.CLOSING: 256>, data=None, extra=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/market-bot/market-bot/bitmax-bot/api/bitmax_api.py", line 225, in handle_messages
    message = await self.dispatch(message)
  File "/home/market-bot/market-bot/bitmax-bot/api/bitmax_api.py", line 201, in dispatch
    raise exc
api.bitmax_api.BitmaxWebSocket.WSClosed: Dispatch: WebSocket apparently closed
WSMessage(type=<WSMsgType.CLOSING: 256>, data=None, extra=None)
```

I'm trying to catch exception to continue the program, but it gets exception and stops working.

Answer (score 0):

`raise exc` in the `except` clause re-raises the exception. Did you mean to include it?

Comment: Yes. It's just propagating exception up.

Comment: But it won't continue the program if you re-raise the exception... @Mr.Danchik

Comment: It's handled in a higher function

Comment: So there ought to be no problem, but there is